# Reinstall RVM resulting in Unrecognized command line argument 'impode'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, terminal, rvm

Before I can say: "I've tried everything", I should post here. So, here is my problem.
I had a problem with `ruby 1.9.3-p194`. My terminal just got stuck on every(!) command involving ruby or rails. (e.g. `rails s mongrel` or even `rails -v` and `ruby -v`)

It all started with this strange thing:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3-p194
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194

$ bundle exec rails s mongrel
```

and then it got stuck.
So, I wanted to know which versions of ruby I got installed:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

ruby-1.8.7-p370 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Huh?! So am I using a non-installed ruby-version?

After some research many advices were to reinstall the whole package.
So, I tried.

```
$ rvm uninstall 1.9.3-p194
Removing /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194...
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 has already been removed.
```

and again, just to make sure..

```
$ rvm uninstall 1.9.3-p194
/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 has already been removed.
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 has already been removed.
```

Well, that looks good. (Except for the fact that half of it was already removed on the first try... :| )
Then:

#### Error #1

```
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p194
Removing /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194...
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 has already been removed.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p194.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #autoreconf
Error running 'autoreconf', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/autoreconf.log
Skipping configure step, 'configure' does not exist, did autoreconf not run successfully?
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #compiling

Error running 'make', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

next step was:

```
$ rvm uninstall 1.9.3-p194
Removing /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194...
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 has already been removed.
Removing default ruby interpreter

$ rvm list

rvm rubies


# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.
```

So I checked the `help install`, but found nothing that might help. At least, I haven't seen a solution..
Next:

#### Error #2

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3-p194
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p194.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p194 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring

Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Now, I wanted to uninstall rvm:

```
$ brew uninstall rvm
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/rvm
```

Okay.. Let's check if it still works..?

```
$ rvm

<listed standard output, thought that'd be useless here..>
```

Yes, it's still there. Let's try to install 1.9.3 again..

#### Error #2 (Same as before..)

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p327.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p327 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #configuring

Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Then I found a 'solution...', #not..

```
$ umask g+w
$ export -a rvm_configure_env
$ rvm_configure_env=('LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib' 'CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include' 'CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include')
```

Didn't work out..
I tried to install 1.9.3 again, which again raised **error #2**

That's it I thought. Let's implode the whole bunch.. (read that as a possible solution)

```
$ rvm implode
Are you SURE you wish for rvm to implode?
This will recursively remove /usr/local/rvm and other rvm traces?
(anything other than 'yes' will cancel) > yes
Removing rvm-shipped binaries (rvm-prompt, rvm, rvm-sudo rvm-shell and rvm-auto-ruby)
Removing rvm wrappers in /usr/local/rvm/bin
Hai! Removing /usr/local/rvm
rm: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: Permission denied
/usr/local/rvm has been removed.
rvm has been fully removed. Note you may need to manually remove /etc/rvmrc and ~/.rvmrc if they exist still.
```

Oh.. `Permission denied` nice...

```
$ sudo rvm implode
Password:
sudo: rvm: command not found
```

Hurrayy! It finally is removed.

Let's install it again..

```
$ gem install rvm
Successfully installed rvm-1.11.3.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rvm-1.11.3.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for rvm-1.11.3.5...
```

What?! After just one try? Okay.. :)
But then....

#### Error #3

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3-p194
cat: /usr/local/rvm/VERSION: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/base: No such file or directory
Unrecognized command line argument: 'impode' ( see: 'rvm usage' )
```

`impode`.. ? Whut?! Well, this is probably from an earlier typo..

Then I tried some other commands returning the same error over and over again:

```
ifonteijne:dash Kers$ rvm install 1.9.3-p194
cat: /usr/local/rvm/VERSION: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/base: No such file or directory
Unrecognized command line argument: 'imstall' ( see: 'rvm usage' )
ifonteijne:dash Kers$ rvm impode
cat: /usr/local/rvm/VERSION: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/base: No such file or directory
Unrecognized command line argument: 'impode' ( see: 'rvm usage' )
ifonteijne:dash Kers$ rvm implode
cat: /usr/local/rvm/VERSION: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/base: No such file or directory
Unrecognized command line argument: 'impode' ( see: 'rvm usage' )
ifonteijne:dash Kers$ rvm install
cat: /usr/local/rvm/VERSION: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/base: No such file or directory
Unrecognized command line argument: 'impode' ( see: 'rvm usage' )
```

Now I am stuck as .....

If someone can help me out, please.

I want to install: `Ruby 1.9.3-p194` through `RVM`

== Edit ==
Tried:

```
$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )

# Kers,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne
```

Well, that worked.

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3-p194
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p194.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
You requested building with '/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' but it is not in your path.

$ brew install gcc
==> Installing gcc dependency: gmp
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gmp/gmp-5.0.5.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/5.0.5 --enable-cxx --build=x86_64-apple-darwin
==> make
==> make check
==> make install
                 (...)
Xcode: 4.5.2 => /Volumes/SATA/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
CLT: 1.0.0.9000000000.1.1249367152
Error: Homebrew doesn't know what compiler versions ship with your version of
Xcode. Please file an issue with the output of `brew --config`:
  https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues

Error: Failed executing: make (mpfr.rb:31)
```

As was said:

```
$ brew --config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.3
HEAD: 360be75b4c4e286365d71664d9a8ab277d7b1fb3
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit arrandale
OS X: 10.8.2-x86_64
Xcode: 4.5.2 => /Volumes/SATA/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
CLT: 1.0.0.9000000000.1.1249367152
GCC-4.2: build 5666
LLVM-GCC: build 2335
Clang: 2.1 build 163
X11: 2.7.3 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: Hi, remove the current rvm again. remove the rvm folder manually if you have to (check to make sure it's gone). remove the rvm related line in your .bashrc and then install rvm again using this command: curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
Then let me know what happens :)

Comment: That worked flawlessly, thank you. Now installing gcc through `brew install --use-llvm gcc`. Because of the Xcode error I mentioned earlier. Thanks again!

Comment: Already for like 30 minutes on `==> make bootstrap`...

Comment: @rik.vanmechelen, yes! I left my macbook at work, checked this morning and it was installed correctly! Thank you so much! Now I'm installing Rails and hopefully I can continue working on my project.  
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it thanks to the comment of [rik.vanmechelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/782031/rik-vanmechelen,).

Conclusion:

#### Remove Ruby

```
$ ruby implode
```

#### Install Ruby

*Note: `==> Make Bootstrap` takes a (very) long time.*

```
$ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

#### Install gcc

*Note: This is not the standard command for it, I used it because of a Xcode 'Command line' error.*

```
$ brew install --use-llvm gcc
```

#### Install Rails

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

Then I was good to go.

[rik.vanmechelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/782031/rik-vanmechelen,), thanks again.